# CodeIgniter: form's action cannot direct to the right path

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

as title says, my form's action seems cannot direct to its path,
this is my form:

```
form action="<?php echo site_url();?>home/search_result_t/?">
   ...
</form
```

so its supposed to direct to

```
example.com/index.php?/home/search_result_t/?from=&to=May+28%2C+Sat
```

instead of go to that link, it refresh my home (example.com) and my CI direct it to

```
example.com/index.php??from=&to=May+28%2C+Sat
```

its like it cannot catch my controller function

any suggestion?
btw, I ran my CI on nginx
and this is the config.php configuration

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: write form action like this <form action="<?php echo site_url();?>home/search_result_t/" ?>
   ...
</form

Comment: still same problem...it just refresing page

Comment: Did you see the HTML code before you to link? Does it show excepted address in `form` element?

Comment: If page is refreshing when you click to form, then it might be problem with route configurations or .htaccess

Comment: I'm using nginx so htaccess obviously does not work, because it only run on apache

Answer (score 0):

Your action is wrong use it like

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url("home/search_result_t");?>" method="get" >
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: still same problem...it just refresing page

Comment: Do you have a controller named `home` and a function in it named as `search_result_t` ?? Also post your routes And your function tooo ....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeigniter, why not use codeigniter forms?

```
<?php
        $attr = [
        "id" => "ajax"
        ];
        echo form_open('home/search_result_t', $attr);
```

Where home is your controller and search_result_t is your function in that controller. It automatically directs it to the right controller

If you are not using an id for your form you dont need the array. Just use

```
echo form_open('home/search_result_t');
```